# Matplotlib first x tick and x tick label position at the origin

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

Sample code to generate plots is as follows:

```
from pandas import DataFrame   
Data = {'Unemployment_Rate': [6.1,5.8,5.7,5.7,5.8,5.6,5.5,5.3,5.2,5.2],
        'Stock_Index_Price': [1500,1520,1525,1523,1515,1540,1545,1560,1555,1565]
       }

df = DataFrame(Data,columns=['Unemployment_Rate','Stock_Index_Price'])
df.plot()
```

The plot and the x tick label start from a position ahead of the the xy coordinate axis. How to begin the plot and x tick label from the origin?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I believe the way the plot turns out on your pc may be slightly different from what I get. But if you want the axes to start from 0, you can use `xlim` and `ylim` from `pyplot`.

Answer (score 0):

Set the [`xlim`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_xlim.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_xlim) on the axes object returned by the `df.plot()`:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

ax = df.plot()
ax.set_xlim(left = 0)
plt.show()
```

Resulting image:

[image]